# Flash unidentified property

Tags: arrays, flash, undefined

For some reason unknown to me it thinks my array pressed keys is not defined. The error is : "Access of undefined property pressedKeys." But the array works fine in my onKeyDown and Up functions.. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

var Entities:Array = new Array();
var PressedKeys:Array = new Array();

//Create player ...more code


function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    updateVel();

    //...
}

function updateVel()
{
    if (pressedKeys[37]) //getting error here
    {
        // left
        player.velX -=  player.speed;
    }
    else if (pressedKeys[65])
    {
        player.velX -=  player.speed;
    }
    if (pressedKeys[38])
    {
        // up 
        player.velY -=  player.speed;
    }
    else if (pressedKeys[87])
    {
        player.velY -=  player.speed;
    }

    //more code...
}

function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    PressedKeys[event.keyCode] = true; //works fine here
    trace("Keycode: " + event.keyCode + " is: " + PressedKeys[event.keyCode]);
}

function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    PressedKeys[event.keyCode] = false;
    trace("Keycode: " + event.keyCode + " is: " + PressedKeys[event.keyCode]);
}

function rand(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number
{
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `PressedKeys` not `pressedKeys` - notice the upper/lower case.